# Why is this Docker CMD producing a zero-length file?

Tags: docker, containers, expect

I created a simple Docker image that can be used to create a keypair with openssl. But when I `docker run` the container, it produces a zero length key file. Yet running the `openssl` command interactively produces a normal sized keyfile. **Why does running via a Docker container not save the contents of the file?**

My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
# Very small Docker image that provides openssl
#
FROM gliderlabs/alpine:3.3
MAINTAINER Dave Hein <someone@example.org>

ARG REFRESHED_AT=2016-05-17T18:29-0500
RUN apk-install --update openssl
RUN apk-install --update expect
WORKDIR /data/root/ca

ARG CMD_AT=2016-05-17T19:42-0500 
CMD mkdir -p certs crl newcerts private && \
    expect -c "spawn openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private/${KEY_NAME}.key.pem 4096" \
    -c "expect \"Enter pass phrase\"" \
    -c "send \"${PP_}\r\"" \
    -c "expect \"Verifying - Enter pass phrase\"" \ 
    -c "send \"${PP_}\r\"" \
    -c "interact" && \
    echo
```

I build the container with this script:

```
#! /bin/bash
#
docker build -t datihein/ca-cert --file Dockerfile .
```

And the script that runs the container looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
#
docker run --rm \
  -e KEY_NAME=datihein -e PP_="wat dat?!" \
  -v /var/lib/dockerdata/root/ca:/data/root/ca \
  datihein/ca-cert
```

I've tried adding `sync` and `sync -f` to the CMD, before the `echo`, but I still end up with a zero-length file in `/var/lib/dockerdata/root/ca/private/datihein.key.pem` on the host.

I suspect the problem has something to do with spawning from within `expect`, but I don't know what to do to force the file to be flushed before the container is torn down.

*(In case it's important, my Docker host system is a boot2docker VM running in VirtualBox on an OS X 10.9.5 system.)*

**UPDATE:** The solution was to use the expect command `wait` to wait for the `openssl` process to terminate before completing the `expect` command and destroying the container. The updated Docker CMD looks like:

```
CMD mkdir -p certs crl newcerts private && \
    expect -c "spawn openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private/${KEY_NAME}.key.pem 4096" \
    -c "expect \"Enter pass phrase\"" \
    -c "send \"${PP_}\r\"" \
    -c "expect \"Verifying - Enter pass phrase\"" \ 
    -c "send \"${PP_}\r\"" \
    -c "wait" && \
    echo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was indeed related to the `spawn` command inside `expect`.

The `expect` command `wait` will wait for a spawned process to complete.

I simply replaced the `interact` command with `wait` and it produced a normal length key file; i.e., the `openssl` command flushed and closed the output file before the container was destroyed.

*(Feh. Perhaps this will help someone else.)*